# Задача про квадратное уравнение | c++

Tags: c++

Даны действительные числа a, b, c. Найдите все решения квадратного уравнения ax² + bx + c = 0.

Написал достаточно простой код, вроде бы работает, но в тест системе не проходит достаточно много тестов. Что делать?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    int d = b*b-4*a*c;
    if (d < 0)
        std::cout << "";
    else if (d == 0)
        std::cout << (-b+sqrt(d))/2*a;
    else
        std::cout << (-b+sqrt(d))/2*a << " " << (-b-sqrt(d))/2*a;
}
```

Comment: А коэффициенты точно **целые**?

Comment: `2*a` -> `(2*a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Замените
   `(-b+sqrt(d))/2*a` на `(-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a)`,
   `(-b-sqrt(d))/2*a` на `(-b-sqrt(d))/(2*a)`.
2. Если вам введут не целые числа - программа не будет работать верно. Чтобы это исправить сделайте переменные `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` типа `double`.